# ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in GET

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to index the pages from gogoanime1.com which contains 'watch/' in the Url.The following worked previously only different sites but for reason , the error like this are in my logs [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-g-next/episode/episode-48/1>

And also none of the data is in my output json

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class GogocrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'gogocrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['gogoanime1.com']
    start_urls = ['http://gogoanime1.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'watch/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
         yield {response.url}
```

Part of my Logs :[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-link-joker-hen/episode/episode-1>
2019-08-13 16:26:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-link-joker-hen/episode/episode-2>
2019-08-13 16:26:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-g-next/episode/episode-43/1>
2019-08-13 16:26:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-g-next/episode/episode-44/1> (referer: https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-g-next/episode/episode-44)
2019-08-13 16:26:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-link-joker-hen/episode/episode-4>
2019-08-13 16:26:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/cardfight-vanguard-link-joker-hen/episode/episode-5>

Comment: `yield {response.url}` this yields a set `{}` but should return `Request`, `BaseItem`, `dict` or `None`, for example `yield scrapy.Request(...)`

Comment: For more info: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error log. You need to return 
**Request, BaseItem, dict or None**.

So this would work for you

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class GogocrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'gogocrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['gogoanime1.com']
    start_urls = ['http://gogoanime1.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'watch/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
         yield {'url':response.url}
```

You should now see data in your output.json